# Imagen SVG desaparece después de animarla con CSS, ¿Cómo evitar que desaparezca?

Tags: css, svg, animación, frontend

Estoy practicando con imagenes `SVG` y las propiedades `stroke-dashoffset` y `stroke-dasharray` (soy muy novato), y he logrado una pequeña animación de un escudo que se forma mediante líneas, pero acabada la animación la imagen desaparece, quisiera que se animara el logotipo y se quedara visible, algo asi como un efecto reveal.

**Anexo enlace al código**

[Proyecto](https://bit.ly/3lNK4CL)

Comment: No, el enlace al código no sirve de nada en [es.so]. Por favor crea un [mcve], tienes la reputación suficiente para saber como funciona el sitio. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código aquí. Con las herramientas que dispones en el sitio hasta podremos ver el problema ejecutando el código, usa un `snippet`, que para eso existen. Tienes mi -1.

Comment: Intenté ponerlo, pero me restringió el número de caracteres en el snipet, por eso lo anexe así.

Comment: Necesitas añadir `animation-fill-mode:forwards`. Por defecto `animation-fill-mode: none`, - o sea el elemento vuelve al punto de partida.  Por de otra parte si utilizas  `animation-fill-mode:forwards`  el elemento se queda en el punto donde acabó la animación.